# Почему при открытии проекта через phpStorm, в url указан localhost:63342? Так же для чего нужен OpenServer в phpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, openserver

Объясните пожалуйста, почему при открытии через phpStorm выводиться localhost:63342, а не 127.0.0.1? Что это такое? И почему при открытии через OpenServer такого нет?Я так же заметил что без OpenServer проект всё равно можно открыть в браузере, через phpStorm. В таком случае для чего тогда  нужен OpenServer PhpStorm'у?

Comment: PhpStorm и OpenServer -- разные вещи. Где Вы прочитали что PhpStorm'у нужен OpenServer?

Comment: localhost - это и есть 127.0.0.1

Comment: Я более того скажу, можно запустить проект на php и без всякого OpenServer и PhpStorm в принципе (подсказка: у php есть встроенный сервер)

Answer (score 0):

localhost и 127.0.0.1 это одно и то же.
В вашем случае имеется еще порт 63342, в отличии от 80 (по умолчанию).

Судя по наличию порта и тому, что проект открывается без запущенного OpenServer, видимо ваш PhpStorm запускает собственный web-сервер. По большому счету, вам вообще не нужен OpenServer, если вас устраивает работа встроенного web-сервера. Отдельный вопрос по базе данных (если она используется).